# RelativeLayout child top is coming as zero

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

am facing a strange problem, I have generated my layout file using RelativeLayout. however while reading top of one of the child's present in it is being returned as zero,which is causing my whole animation logic go for toss.

My idea is to animate them from bottom of screen, to there initial position. below is my code, any help from you all will be highly appreciated.

My layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="35dp"
    android:paddingRight="35dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/msgs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/share"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="26dp"
            android:typeface="monospace" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:text="@string/share_message"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:typeface="sans" />
    </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/view_twitter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/msgs"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/circle_twitter" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/view_facebook"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/msgs"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/view_twitter"
        android:src="@drawable/facebook_circle" />



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/view_google"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/msgs"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/view_twitter"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/google_circle" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My Fragment code, where am animating them

```
import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.Animator.AnimatorListener;
import android.animation.AnimatorSet;
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator;

public class IntroFragmentThird extends Fragment{

    View google;
    View twitter;
    View facebook;
    View messagePanel;
    int screenHeight;
    int screenWidth;
    int offset;
    float beginPoint;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        screenWidth = size.x;
        screenHeight = size.y;
        offset = screenHeight + 200; // start from 200px below screen height
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.intro3_layout, container, false);
        google = view.findViewById(R.id.view_google);
        facebook = view.findViewById(R.id.view_facebook);
        twitter = view.findViewById(R.id.view_twitter);
        messagePanel = view.findViewById(R.id.msgs);

        google.setVisibility(View.GONE); // Initial view visibility will be gone
        facebook.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        twitter.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        beginPoint = twitter.getTop(); // this is coming as ZERO

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        System.out.println("#### Top : " + beginPoint);
        playScreenAnimation();
    }

    public void playScreenAnimation(){

        facebook.clearAnimation();
        facebook.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        facebook.clearAnimation();
        facebook.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        facebook.clearAnimation();
        facebook.setVisibility(View.GONE);




        ObjectAnimator anim1 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(facebook, "y", offset , beginPoint);
        anim1.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        anim1.setDuration(1000);
        anim1.setStartDelay(1000);
        anim1.addListener(new AnimatorListener(){

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                facebook.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });

        ObjectAnimator anim2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(twitter, "y", offset , beginPoint);
        anim2.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        anim2.setDuration(1000);
        anim2.addListener(new AnimatorListener(){

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                twitter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });

        ObjectAnimator anim3 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(google, "y", offset , beginPoint);
        anim3.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        anim3.setDuration(1000);
        anim3.setStartDelay(1000);
        anim3.addListener(new AnimatorListener(){

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                google.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });


        AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
        set.playTogether(anim2,anim1,anim3);
        set.start();
    }

}
```

Here is screenshot of, initial state of views (those three fb, g+, twitter circles are being animated)

[image]

Comment: use INVISIBLE insted GONE n try ...

Comment: Nopes it didn't worked still top is coming as zero @MSGadag

Comment: k n sry im not gettin you...

Comment: Basically it didn't worked, even by setting visibility to INVISIBLE top of view(R.id.view_twitter, that twitter circle in screenshot) is being returned to ZERO only.

Comment: animation is working rite but end of the animation ur ui is disterbed rite?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64993/discussion-between-techfist-and-m-s-gadag).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I solved it, instead of using object animator, i ended up using view animation, and animating views considering there relative positions.

```
    facebook.clearAnimation();
    facebook.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    google.clearAnimation();
    google.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    twitter.clearAnimation();
    twitter.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    TranslateAnimation anim1 = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0
            ,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,offset,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0);
    anim1.setDuration(1000);
    anim1.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    anim1.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener(){

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            facebook.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });



    TranslateAnimation anim2 = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0
            ,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,offset,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0);
    anim2.setDuration(750);
    //anim2.setStartOffset(500);
    anim2.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    anim2.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener(){

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            twitter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });



    TranslateAnimation anim3 = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0
            ,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,offset,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0);
    anim3.setDuration(750);
    anim3.setStartOffset(500);
    anim3.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    anim3.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener(){

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            google.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });

    twitter.startAnimation(anim2);
    facebook.startAnimation(anim1);
    google.startAnimation(anim3);
```